# After Magento 1.9.1.0 I can't place orders. undefined javascript alert

Tags: magento

I just upgraded my Magento store from 1.6.0 to 1.9.1 and when I add products to cart everything goes well until I proceed to checkout.

I fill the checkout information, select a shipping method (some of the shipping methods display the "This shipping method is currently unavailable..." error message) and click on Place Order button, after a few seconds I got a javascript alert with "undefined" and nothing else happens.

Any ideas on where to start looking up to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check using firebug extension in Firefox, for more details of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to the `form_key` not being set.

- Go to `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/checkout/onepage/review.phtml` OR to `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml`
- The following code will be either in `review.phtml` or in `info.phtml` file:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
      var review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder') ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
  //]]>
  </script>
  ```
- Change it to the following:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
      var review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
  //]]>
  </script>
  ```

So, basically, the solution is just to add the `form_key` to the `saveOrder` URL.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue and i fixed it by removing my checkout module .

Answer (score 0):

The answere might be a missing formkey in the info.phtml file. After one of the SUPPEE Patches the template needs formkeys on different forms including the one for the final place order handling.

Please find a complete answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/19743